# Filled barplot and density curve

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, density-plot

I am trying to create a bar graph with a density curve that shows the bar trends, see the example in the figure 1 (I created this example by PowerPoint).
The fill corresponds to the Time column, the y to the abundance value and the x to the species.

However, in the script I wrote, I couldn't this plot.
Would anyone here know how to improve my script?

```js
data<-read.csv(file= "data.csv", header= TRUE, sep= ";" )
names(data)

library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

mu <- ddply(data, "Time", summarise, grp.mean=mean(body_mass))
head(mu)


ggplot(data, aes(x=body_mass, y=Abund, color=Time, fill=Time)) +
geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), position="identity", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_density(alpha=0.6)+
  geom_vline(data=mu, aes(xintercept=grp.mean, color=warfare),
             linetype="dashed")+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#FF1234"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#FF1234"))+
  labs(title="Abundance",x="body mass", y = "abundancey")+
  theme_classic()
```

```html
specie body_mass Time Abund
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 2
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 3
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 3
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 2
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 2
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 3
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 3
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 2
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 4
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 2
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 2
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 4
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 3
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 2
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 4
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 3
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 3
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 3
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 3
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 3
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 3
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 4
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 4
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 2
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 3
sp1 3824539.93 Time1 2
sp2 1536310.4 Time1 3
sp2 1536310.4 Time1 3
sp2 1536310.4 Time1 2
sp2 1536310.4 Time1 2
sp2 1536310.4 Time1 2
sp2 1536310.4 Time1 2
sp2 1536310.4 Time1 2
sp2 1536310.4 Time1 1
sp2 1536310.4 Time1 2
sp2 1536310.4 Time1 2
sp2 1536310.4 Time1 1
sp2 1536310.4 Time1 1
sp2 1536310.4 Time1 2
sp2 1536310.4 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 2
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 2
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 2
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 2
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 2
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 2
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 3
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 2
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp3 592665.98 Time1 4
sp4 562592.69 Time1 1
sp4 562592.69 Time1 1
sp4 562592.69 Time1 1
sp4 562592.69 Time1 1
sp4 562592.69 Time1 1
sp4 562592.69 Time1 1
sp4 562592.69 Time1 1
sp4 562592.69 Time1 3
sp4 562592.69 Time1 4
sp4 562592.69 Time1 3
sp4 562592.69 Time1 3
sp4 562592.69 Time1 3
sp4 562592.69 Time1 2
sp4 562592.69 Time1 4
sp4 562592.69 Time1 3
sp4 562592.69 Time1 3
sp4 562592.69 Time1 3
sp4 562592.69 Time1 3
sp4 562592.69 Time1 3
sp4 562592.69 Time1 3
sp4 562592.69 Time1 2
sp4 562592.69 Time1 1
sp4 562592.69 Time1 3
sp5 264173.96 Time1 1
sp5 264173.96 Time1 1
sp5 264173.96 Time1 3
sp5 264173.96 Time1 4
sp5 264173.96 Time1 1
sp5 264173.96 Time1 2
sp5 264173.96 Time1 3
sp5 264173.96 Time1 2
sp5 264173.96 Time1 2
sp5 264173.96 Time1 3
sp5 264173.96 Time1 3
sp5 264173.96 Time1 2
sp5 264173.96 Time1 2
sp5 264173.96 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 1
sp6 158623.93 Time1 1
sp6 158623.93 Time1 3
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 1
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 1
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 1
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 3
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 3
sp6 158623.93 Time1 3
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 3
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 1
sp6 158623.93 Time1 3
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 3
sp6 158623.93 Time1 3
sp6 158623.93 Time1 1
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 1
sp6 158623.93 Time1 3
sp6 158623.93 Time1 3
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 1
sp6 158623.93 Time1 3
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 3
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 2
sp6 158623.93 Time1 1
sp6 158623.93 Time1 3
sp6 158623.93 Time1 3
sp6 158623.93 Time1 3
sp6 158623.93 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 2
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 2
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 2
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 2
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 2
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 3
sp7 69063.79 Time1 4
sp8 63369.98 Time1 2
sp8 63369.98 Time1 2
sp8 63369.98 Time1 2
sp8 63369.98 Time1 2
sp8 63369.98 Time1 2
sp8 63369.98 Time1 1
sp8 63369.98 Time1 1
sp8 63369.98 Time1 2
sp8 63369.98 Time1 2
sp8 63369.98 Time1 3
sp8 63369.98 Time1 2
sp8 63369.98 Time1 2
sp8 63369.98 Time1 2
sp8 63369.98 Time1 2
sp8 63369.98 Time1 2
sp8 63369.98 Time1 2
sp8 63369.98 Time1 3
sp8 63369.98 Time1 3
sp8 63369.98 Time1 2
sp8 63369.98 Time1 2
sp10 56175.2 Time1 2
sp10 56175.2 Time1 3
sp10 56175.2 Time1 3
sp10 56175.2 Time1 3
sp10 56175.2 Time1 2
sp10 56175.2 Time1 2
sp10 56175.2 Time1 3
sp10 56175.2 Time1 2
sp10 56175.2 Time1 2
sp10 56175.2 Time1 2
sp10 56175.2 Time1 3
sp10 56175.2 Time1 2
sp10 56175.2 Time1 1
sp10 56175.2 Time1 1
sp10 56175.2 Time1 2
sp10 56175.2 Time1 2
sp10 56175.2 Time1 2
sp10 56175.2 Time1 2
sp10 56175.2 Time1 1
sp10 56175.2 Time1 1
sp10 56175.2 Time1 2
sp10 56175.2 Time1 3
sp10 56175.2 Time1 2
sp10 56175.2 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 3
sp11 52399.99 Time1 3
sp11 52399.99 Time1 3
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 3
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 1
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 3
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 3
sp11 52399.99 Time1 3
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 3
sp11 52399.99 Time1 3
sp11 52399.99 Time1 3
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 3
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 3
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 3
sp11 52399.99 Time1 3
sp11 52399.99 Time1 3
sp11 52399.99 Time1 1
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 3
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 3
sp11 52399.99 Time1 3
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 1
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp11 52399.99 Time1 2
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 2
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 2
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 2
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 2
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 2
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 0
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp1 3824539.93 Time2 1
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 2
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 2
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 2
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 2
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 2
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 1
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 3
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 1
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 3
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 3
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 1
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 2
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 2
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 2
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 1
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 1
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 1
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 0
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 1
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 1
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 1
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 2
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 1
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 0
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 1
sp2 1536310.4 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 2
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 2
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 2
sp3 592665.98 Time2 2
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 2
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 2
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 2
sp3 592665.98 Time2 2
sp3 592665.98 Time2 2
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 2
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 0
sp3 592665.98 Time2 1
sp4 562592.69 Time2 0
sp4 562592.69 Time2 0
sp4 562592.69 Time2 0
sp4 562592.69 Time2 0
sp4 562592.69 Time2 0
sp4 562592.69 Time2 1
sp4 562592.69 Time2 0
sp4 562592.69 Time2 0
sp4 562592.69 Time2 0
sp4 562592.69 Time2 0
sp4 562592.69 Time2 0
sp4 562592.69 Time2 0
sp4 562592.69 Time2 0
sp4 562592.69 Time2 0
sp4 562592.69 Time2 0
sp4 562592.69 Time2 0
sp4 562592.69 Time2 0
sp4 562592.69 Time2 0
sp4 562592.69 Time2 0
sp4 562592.69 Time2 0
sp5 264173.96 Time2 0
sp5 264173.96 Time2 0
sp5 264173.96 Time2 0
sp5 264173.96 Time2 0
sp5 264173.96 Time2 0
sp5 264173.96 Time2 0
sp5 264173.96 Time2 0
sp5 264173.96 Time2 0
sp5 264173.96 Time2 0
sp5 264173.96 Time2 0
sp5 264173.96 Time2 0
sp5 264173.96 Time2 0
sp5 264173.96 Time2 0
sp5 264173.96 Time2 0
sp5 264173.96 Time2 0
sp5 264173.96 Time2 0
sp5 264173.96 Time2 0
sp5 264173.96 Time2 0
sp5 264173.96 Time2 0
sp5 264173.96 Time2 0
sp5 264173.96 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 2
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 2
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 2
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 2
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 1
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 2
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 0
sp6 158623.93 Time2 2
sp6 158623.93 Time2 2
sp6 158623.93 Time2 2
sp6 158623.93 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 4
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 4
sp7 69063.79 Time2 4
sp7 69063.79 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 4
sp7 69063.79 Time2 4
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 4
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 1
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 4
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 4
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 1
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 1
sp7 69063.79 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 1
sp7 69063.79 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 1
sp7 69063.79 Time2 1
sp7 69063.79 Time2 2
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp7 69063.79 Time2 3
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 2
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 1
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 1
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0
sp8 63369.98 Time2 0 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 0
sp11 52399.99 Time2 0
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 2
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 2
sp11 52399.99 Time2 2
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 3
sp11 52399.99 Time2 2
sp11 52399.99 Time2 3
sp11 52399.99 Time2 2
sp11 52399.99 Time2 2
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 2
sp11 52399.99 Time2 2
sp11 52399.99 Time2 3
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 3
sp11 52399.99 Time2 2
sp11 52399.99 Time2 2
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 2
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 2
sp11 52399.99 Time2 3
sp11 52399.99 Time2 2
sp11 52399.99 Time2 2
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 2
sp11 52399.99 Time2 2
sp11 52399.99 Time2 3
sp11 52399.99 Time2 2
sp11 52399.99 Time2 2
sp11 52399.99 Time2 3
sp11 52399.99 Time2 3
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 3
sp11 52399.99 Time2 2
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 3
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 3
sp11 52399.99 Time2 3
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 0
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 0
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 1
sp11 52399.99 Time2 0
sp11 52399.99 Time2 0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

look over this line geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), i suspect this is where your error is arising